# Fast Fourier Transform polynomial multiplication?

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science, fft

I am using the FFT to evaluate a polynomial at certain points so that it can be represented using value representation. (representation as a number of points equal to its degree)

However to multiply two polynomials of degree d, I need to evaluate both at 2d + 1 points. However using the FFT for evaluation (multiplying by the dth roots of unity) only evaluates the polynomial at d points. Therefore how can the FFT be used for evaluation for polynomial evaluation if it only evaluates a polynomial at d points? (as opposed to 2d + 1)

Comment: Are you trying to multiply two polynomials together? Or are you trying to evaluate a polynomial at a bunch of points. Can you clarify? Your question seems to contradict itself.

Comment: I am multiplying two polynomials. However to multiply the polynomials, I need to evaluate them at a certain number of points, multiply them in value representations and the use interpolation to transform the points back to coefficients. Therefore my question is among about multiplication AND evaluation.

Comment: You don't need to evaluate the polynomial at any points to multiply them together. Just FFT the coefficients directly.

Comment: I know- that *would* be a simpler solution. However I'm in a situation where I need to FFT points not coeffcients. Sorry, I am not allowed to share exactly why I have this restraint.

Comment: Oh ok. I'm not familiar with the topic of FFT polynomial evaluation.

Comment: Do you mean `2d + 1` rather than `2d - 1` (`2d-1` seems too small, given that the space of polynomials of degree `d` has dimension `d+1`).

Comment: The important thing to note is that multiplying two polynomials is the same as convolving the coefficients.

Comment: @MarkBorgerding Yes, your right. Sorry about that- I corrected it in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get to choose which n-th roots of -1 you evaluate at. If you need 2d-1 points (as I suspect you do) just use the (2d-1)-th roots of -1. In fact, you would normally use the 2^k-th roots of -1, where 2^k is the first power of 2 >= 2d-1, because it is much easier to get fast FFT for powers of 2. The complexity is still O(d log d) because the definition of O allows for constant factors.